# Advanced Installer- How to create MySQL user during installer?

Tags: mysql, installation, windows-installer, advanced-installer

Im ready to deploy my project and I'm using Advanced Installer to package it. My project does involved a Database connection. My goal is during installation I will have a dialog that will ask user to setup a username and password for MYSQL database connection (and perhaps other mysql server fields).

How can I achieve this using Advanced Installer?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You could run a script (either inline VBScript or a batch script which accepts the user input as arguments) to in turn run the MySQL command line tool and add the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is their user guide [tutorial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-sql.html) about how to run sql scripts during installation. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

To Enter the your database credentials first you need design the dialog.to design the dialog you go under dialog option and create a new dialog by right clicking the any other dialog you need to click on the option called add dialog in add dialog you will get a popup box by asking which type of dialog where you need to select sql connection dialog click on that and you will get what you want on start up...

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Custom Actions" page and create a new "Launch EXE with working directory" custom action with sequence under the "Install Execution Stage -> Searches" action group like this:

   File Path: mysqld
   Command: --install

   Working: Path to mysql\bin\
2. Add a new "Launch file" custom action with sequence, scheduled after the above one, like this:

   File To Launch: cmd.exe
   Command Line: /c NET START mysql

Working Directory:
Run as Adminsitrator: checked
For configuring the MySQL Server you can use a BAT file as a custom action after MySQL server is installed.